# Rails 6 Production processing html template instead js when call AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, production

I have problem with rails 6.1.1 and ruby 2.7.2 in production mode when using ajax call as below:

View:

```
    <% if pre_follow %> 
    <%= button_to company_company_follow_path(@company, pre_follow), :method => :delete, remote: true, form_class: "follow_btn_highlight" do%>
        <i class="material-icons">favorite</i> <span>Follow</span>
    <%end%> 
<%else%>
    <%= button_to company_company_follows_path(@company), :method => :post, remote: true, form_class: "follow_btn" do%>
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">favorite_border</i> <span>Unfollow</span>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Controller:

```
def create
    @company = Company.friendly.find(params[:company_id])
    if logged_in?
        if already_followed?
            # flash[:notice] = "You can't like more than once"
        else                
            @company_follow = @company.company_follows.create(user_id: current_user.id)
        end
        # redirect_to company_path(@company)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {}
            format.js
        end
    else
        redirect_to login_path
    end
end

def destroy
    @company = Company.friendly.find(params[:company_id])
    @company_follow = @company.company_follows.find(params[:id])
    @company_follow.destroy
    # redirect_to company_path(@company)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {}
        format.js
    end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#company_follow_<%=@company.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "company_follows/follow_company", locals: {company: @company})%>");
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#company_follow_<%=@company.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "company_follows/follow_company", locals: {company: @company}) %>");
```

When I trace the log in development, it is work fine:

```
    Processing by CompanyFollowsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"l4rFeqGv3b7AdtOLgiKSsQAvE2SikWk1rF865W6JGz7PIf737tLIXXd/kl4vbG09FiDgZxHgz1N2Agm6Px4j/w==", "company_id"=>"fpt"}
  Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "fpt"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/company_follows_controller.rb:15:in `create'
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/session_helper.rb:15:in `current_user'
  CompanyFollow Exists? (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "company_follows" WHERE "company_follows"."user_id" = $1 AND "company_follows"."company_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 1], ["company_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/company_follows_controller.rb:55:in `already_followed?'
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/company_follows_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/company_follows_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  CompanyFollow Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "company_follows" ("created_at", "updated_at", "company_id", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-04-18 08:53:09.700773"], ["updated_at", "2021-04-18 08:53:09.700773"], ["company_id", 5], ["user_id", 1]]
```

But in production log, it false, html template was call instead js template:

```
Processing by CompanyFollowsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"t9ahfM2knA1zSUGvQjAVCArbaqZIuQDg6p0vkekMab9tYqOU1PnzrZwAoKEmkToX9oKGLb6w7BpEx//RnGnq1Q==", "company_id"=>"grab-vietnam-ltd"}
  [1m[36mCompany Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["slug", "grab-vietnam-ltd"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCompanyFollow Exists? (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "company_follows" WHERE "company_follows"."user_id" = $1 AND "company_follows"."company_id" = $2 LIMIT $3[0m  [["user_id", 2], ["company_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE User Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[36mCompanyFollow Create (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "company_follows" ("created_at", "updated_at", "company_id", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["created_at", "2021-04-18 15:08:22.212819"], ["updated_at", "2021-04-18 15:08:22.212819"], ["company_id", 8], ["user_id", 2]]
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (2.7ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 5.2ms | Allocations: 3305)
  
ActionController::UnknownFormat (CompanyFollowsController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []):
enter code here
```

Dose any one tell me why i got this problem and how can I fix it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure rails-ujs / assets are loaded correctly in production? If rails-ujs / @rails/ujs are not loaded, all the data-remote / data-method will not work.

Comment: Thank you for comment but I have added it in javascripts/pack/application.js and production not work.

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

how can I confirm rails-ujs loaded in production?

Comment: If it work, then in a production site's Browser Console you can enter ``$.rails`` and that should respond to something. 
Normally, when having asset issues in productions, make sure: 1. that your prod system has nodejs installed, 2. that ``rails assets:precompile`` runs without errors.

Comment: @stwienert, when i change the application.js file and deploy using capistrano, rails assets:precompile task will build new js package and rails-ujs working success. But, in the next deploy, js package not build, and rails-ujs failed. Do you known how can I force rebuild js-package in each deploy task? thank you!